# (e)lisp を記述している際に、閉じカッコの間の改行・スペースをつぶしたい

Tags: emacs, elisp

emacs 上で (e)lisp を記述していると、関数の記述途中では例えば次のような形になります。

```
(defun plus1-square (n)
  (let ((np1 (+ n 1)))
    (* np1 np1)
    )
  )
```

このように記述された (e)lisp 式を、次のように整形したいです。

```
(defun plus1-square (n)
  (let ((np1 (+ n 1)))
    (* np1 np1)))
```

これを効率的に実現する方法はありますか。今だと、手で改行とスペースの削除を行っているので、効率が悪いと感じているために、質問しています。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[elisp-format](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispFormat)を使うとリージョンやバッファ単位でフォーマットしてくれます。

質問の最初のS式なら、関数中にカーソルがある状態で `M-C-a` `M-C-SPC` `M-x` `elisp-format-region` `RET` で。